# Reference label in polyglossia for hebrew

Tags: cross-referencing

When I compile the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Frank Ruehl CLM}

\begin{document}
נתחיל לכתוב.
\begin{enumerate}
\item\label{1}
פרה שיכורה.
\begin{enumerate}
\item\label{1a}
ירח עליז.
\item\label{1b}
ירח עם גבינה.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
לסיכום: 
\ref{1},\ref{1a},\ref{1b}.
\end{document}
```

I get 1ב instead 1א as output of \ref{1a}.

How to explain it and how to fix this problem?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The counter is not correctly expanded in the aux. You get entries like `\newlabel{1a}{{1\@alph \c@enumii }{1}}`. Imho this is a bug in polyglossia definitions for hebrew and you should report it.

Comment: Now reported [here](https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/197), since I found no earlier report.

Comment: Any news with this question? Have you found some solution, or workaround?