# Polyglossia messes references in Hebrew blocks

Tags: xetex, polyglossia

As a follow-up to [another issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/406719/46339) I've noticed with Hebrew blocks using `polyglossia`, I also encountered the following problem with references: all references to a list in Hebrew blocks appear as to the last item of that list.

A minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}

\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew,Scale=1.0]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Scale=1.0]{Times New Roman}%[Script=English]

\begin{document}

\begin{english}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}
\item\label{oneA}
A

\item\label{oneB}
B
\end{enumerate}

\item
Two \label{two}
\end{enumerate}

We refer to Item 
\ref{oneA}
and 
\ref{oneB}.
\end{english}


\begin{hebrew}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}
\item\label{oneA_h}
א'.

\item\label{oneB_h}
ב'.
\end{enumerate}

\item\label{two_h}
שתיים.

\end{enumerate}

אנחנו מקשרים לסעיף
\ref{oneA_h}
וסעיף
\ref{oneB_h}.
\end{hebrew}

\end{document}
```

which generates the following:
[image]

A couple of things to note:

- The inclusion of `hyperref` doesn't change this behavior; it's done here to demonstrate that while both references in the Hebrew block appear as if they're to the last item (`1ב`), in fact the hyperlink does point to the correct item.
- Using more sophisticated list packages (such as `enumitem`) doesn't affect the issue either; I believe it's caused by `polyglossia`.
- I've ignored what seems to be an unrelated issue, whereby both references appear as `1b` in the Hebrew block; I got the `1ב`'s as a side-effect of including `hyperref`, but only on the 2nd compilation (they revert to `1b`'s after the 3rd compilation). Regardless, the first reference never exhibits as `1a` or `1א`. (This does get fixed by the workaround @UlrikeFischer suggested on my linked question.)

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264089/reference-label-in-polyglossia-for-hebrew

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you! I missed that question in my initial search. Should I close this one?

Comment: Any news with this question? Have you found some solution, or workaround?